# What stops someone from stealing your app code?

Tags: android

I read that apks can easily be decompiled. So what's to stop someone from taking your hard work, changing the icon and package name, and uploading it to the playstore?

Comment: proguard is better than nothing

Comment: Even with that obfuscation stuff they can still change a few statements here and there that will compile differently but give the same result. Can google detect when compiled code is similar to other compiled code that its search engine found? I mean like how it detects when an app uses something from Google Images.